# apache2 installation

Tags: ubuntu-9.10

i have just installed apache2 on my ubuntu shell,..but when i'm trying to test apache on my server with a command

http://localhost/apache2-default/

it's showing server not found...

what should i do???

need help!!!

Comment: Stack Overflow is about programming. Maybe you wanted to post this on Server Fault?

Comment: How exactly did you install apache? What do you get when you visit `http://localhost/`?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if apache is running by writing

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

in your shell.

If apache is not running you can start it with either

```
apache2ctl start
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Answer (score 1):

did you start the server by using 'apachectl' command?
assuming you did, go to the shell and type,

```
ps -ef | grep httpd
```

If you can see a process named 'httpd' running then the installation works. And there might be some error in the url you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try
    `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2`
in the termainal to start apache

Answer (score -1):

hey that one is working now....but starting the apache is giving an error

Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName

i thought that i need to make change to httpd.conf file ,...but i'm not able to do so ...

can someone explain how to do that